# Most efficiet way to determine if there are messages in Azure Storage Queue

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I'm beginning a project which will involve Azure Queue (not Service Bus).
I'm trying to figure out what is the best practice to find out whether there are messages waiting in the Queue.

AFAIK, there are two methods for that:

1. Using the *ApproximateMessageCount* property of the Queue object
2. Calling *GetMessage*, and if the returned value is null - there are no messages.

Which one is better performance-wise? Is there any difference?

From a billing POV, I understand there is a transaction cost for both of them, is that correct?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GetMessage is both faster and cheaper.  GetMessage is also more correct from a logic perspective since the message count will return both messages that have already been retrieved by another reader as well as messages that have expired without being deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I have also used this code in the past:

```
var cnnString = "the connection string";
var queueName = "the queue name";

var nsManager = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(cnnString);
return nsManager.GetQueue(queueName).MessageCount;
```

That said - this was from about 4 months ago.

Any reason you need to do this (i.e. are you not just consuming messages off the queue?)

Comment: The main reason is performance. I would like to use the quicker, less-resource-intensive approach, and I'm not sure if there is a difference between those approaches.

Comment: Performance compared to what?  I'm still a little unclear as to what you're trying to achieve (yes, count the messages on the queue...but why?)

Comment: OK, let my clarify: I want to check whether there are messages in the queue, and if so - to get the first one. The first way to do that is by calling GetMessage, which will return null if empty. The second option is to call ApproximateMessageCount, and if the number is greater than 0, get the message. My question is - when the queue is empty, which option will have a better performance?